# Microsoft MVC Validation.js: watch/create event to run custom function on real form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I use MicrosoftMVCValidation.js to validate a form (client side / no ajax).

When the submit button is clicked, the form is submitted. If there is some invalid form field then an error message is shown instead of sending the data to the server.

I want know how to add custom function only when the form is really submitted to the server.

So for example, I can add a simple js function that disables the submit button and shows a 'loading' image, but only when it was really submitted to the server. I don't want to disable the button if only a validation message shows.

I cant use the onSubmit event because it does't assure that the form was submitted to the server.

So how I can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is a hack you might use but quite frankly consider jquery:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function () {
        // Determine if there are validation errors
        var errors = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm(this).validate('submit');
        if (errors.length < 1) {
            // disable the button if there are no errors
            document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = 'disabled';
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Translate this function to jQuery or use the jQuery MVC validation library?

Comment: Ok... but the function checks for the error message before the form is submitted, but the error messages show only after the form is submitted so the function will never call.

Comment: No, here we are talking about client side validation error messages which happen before the form is submitted. After the form is submitted the whole page is reloaded (you said you don't use AJAX) so your submit button will be reenabled automatically and you shouldn't care about it.